# Android: Broadcast receiver is not listening when the Application is clearing from recents

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am  trying to make an application to listen those app in **Foreground**.

For this am using **Broadcast receiver** to listen the app that are in **foreground**. Am getting **Toast** for each comes in foreground when ever my application is in the **recent list/ background**.

When I clears my application form recent list, then am not getting any **Toast** when the application is comes in **Forground**.

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >     
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.checkcurrentrunningapplication.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="StartupReceiver_Manual_Start" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name = ".CheckRunningApplicationReceiver"/>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

**Receiver class**

```
CheckRunningApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public final String TAG = "CRAR"; // CheckRunningApplicationReceiver
@Override
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {  
    try {   
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am
                .getRunningTasks(1);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {

            if(aTask.topActivity.getClassName().toString().trim().length() > 0)
            Toast.makeText(aContext, "RunningTaskInfo. "+aTask.topActivity.getClassName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Throwable caught: "
                    + t.getMessage(), t);
    }
```

Comment: The receiver does not have any intent-filter in the manifest so it actually cannot react to anything. Care to share the the main activity or something similar?

Comment: Ok Thanks, for listen the application in Foreground which intent filter should I use, any suggestion  @GPuschka